# Does not show simple network management protocol in windows 10 issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, snmp

My step is these..

1. Right-click on the Windows Start button and choose Control Panel.
2. Select Programs from within the Control Panel, then, under Programs and Features, select Turn Windows features on or off.
3. Find the Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) in the list of features and check the checkbox.

I can't find the Simple Network Management Protocol in the list of features..

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 are you using? Most such features are only available in Professional and Enterprise editions.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro , OS build 18363.836

Comment: Sounds like they are on the verge to remove that unfinished feature, https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/snmp-missing-from-windows-features-in-windows-10/6a22f52b-3a88-419c-a54e-d26f18cbafee